# GroupBy multiple columns and find duplicates

Tags: c#, linq

Using c# `Sytem.Linq`here.

I wanted to find the duplicates in my table. A duplicate is defined when the combination of three columns already exists in the table.

For example, below is a duplicate record:

```
Row Id Name Value Status
 1  1  Peter 1    New
 2  1  Peter 1    Old
 3  1  Peter 1    Pending
 4  2  Peter 1    New
 5  2  Sandy 2    Old
```

In the above table Rows 1, 2 and 3 are duplicates. So I wrote the below query to find all duplicates:

```
//Below response holds all data from my db
var result = response
                 .GroupBy(o => new { o.Id, o.Name, o.Value })
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                 .Select(y => y.Key)
                 .ToList();
```

My above query shows all results in the data and not duplicates. What did I do wrong here?

I want the query to just return duplicates as per the aforementioned condition.

Comment: What does this return for you? It should return a single row.

Comment: I do not see any problem with your code...

Comment: As others before have said this should work. That being said - assuming you are using `LinqToEntities`, check that you've marked the `Id` column with the `[Key]` attribute, and that your table has a primary key. I remember having some weird behavior with `GroupBy` and `Distinct` when querying against a view which didn't have a PK defined, and adding a PK solved everything.

Comment: Please provide a small, self-contained program that clearly reproduces the problem that we can run.  When you make your small repro, you'll probably discover the problem yourself. If you don't, then you'll have something we can run and look at.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. There was an issue with my actual data coming from my database itself. The above query works fine. Sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: Per Karen's comment, voting to close as being caused by an issue that cannot be reproduced (i.e., because the described issue is not in this code).

Comment: You should probably delete the question then.

Comment: It doesnt let me delete.

Comment: Yes it does, there is a delete button if you look hard enough :)

Comment: I tried that before, it says: You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center. May be I dont have enough points.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code at https://dotnetfiddle.net and it works fine.  Your problem may be elsewhere.  Here's what I tried that works:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var response = new [] {
            new { Id = 1, Name = "Peter", Value = 1, Status = "New" },
            new { Id = 1, Name = "Peter", Value = 1, Status = "Old" },
            new { Id = 1, Name = "Peter", Value = 1, Status = "Pending" },
            new { Id = 2, Name = "Peter", Value = 1, Status = "New" },
            new { Id = 2, Name = "Sandy", Value = 2, Status = "Old" }
        };
        var result = response
                 .GroupBy(o => new { o.Id, o.Name, o.Value })
                 .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                 .Select(y => y.Key)
                 .ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
    }
}
```

Output:

`{ Id = 1, Name = Peter, Value = 1 }`

Comment: We can all see the questions premise is wrong, I'm not sure how this answer helps at all beyond the comments already made.

Comment: @DavidG I think it helps because this is a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable _counter-example_.  The OP can now compare their own approach to this approach and spot the differences.  I used the original code as-is without modification and just filled in the blanks to demonstrate the details of what was omitted from the original post are likely the cause of the problem.  It also serves as a framework for them to create their own MCVE.

Comment: But the code in the question does exactly the same as your example, that's why it's not useful. Even the OP has admitted that too.